# How to print a dictionary in a `rich.panel.Panel` object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, pretty-print, rich

As the question says, I want to pretty print a dictionary such as `locals()` but in a Panel object (surrounding the dictionary in a nice rectangle).

On trying the naïve approach, i.e.,

```py
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich import print

print(Panel(locals()))
```

I'd get `NotRenderableError: Unable to render ...; A str, Segment or object with __rich_console__ method is required`

The best I could do was convert the dictionary into a `renderable` by digging the source-code.

```py
from rich.console import Console


def do(x):
    c = Console()
    print(Panel(c._collect_renderables(x, sep='\n', end='')))

do(globals())
```

But all it did was print the keys in a box

```
╭───────────────╮
│ dataset_path  │                                                                     
│ layouts       │                                                                            
│ line_level    │                                                                            
│ n             │                                                                            
╰───────────────╯
```

Can anyone suggest the right document I must go through to accomplish this, and in general what is the right way to understand how to utilize `rich` to its fullest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than what I thought..

```py
from rich import print
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.console import Console
from rich.text import Text


def print_box(x, title=None):
    console = Console()
    with console.capture() as capture:
        console.print(x)
    str_output = capture.get()
    text = Text.from_ansi(str_output)
    print(Panel(text, title=title, padding=2))
```

1. Capture the text in a console output
2. Convert it to `Text` object, and
3. Display in a Panel

```
╭───────────────────────────────────────── Inputs ──────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│                                                                                           │
│  {'dataset_path': '/tmp/', 'layouts': '0,1,2,3', 'line_level': False, 'n': None}          │
│                                                                                           │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```